# Generate Commission Junction URLs for all retailer products?

Tags: commission-junction

How can I generate links that will provide me with Commission Junction payouts without grabbing the links from them directly?

I have the URL from the retailer - can I just plop something on the end to get the referrer? Or perhaps add some HTML header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to wrap that URL in the `url=` parameter on any CJ redirect domain along with your publisher id (PID) and any valid link ID for that advertiser.

What you need to construct is a URL that like this:

```
http://<cj-root-domain>/click-<your-pid>-<advertiser-link-id>?url=<url-encoded-redirect-link>
```

E.g.:

```
http://www.jdoqocy.com/click-1245-10888587?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jewelry.com%2Fdaily-deal.shtml
```

So...

1. Pick a CJ root domain to link on. www.anrdoezrs.net, www.tkqlhce.com or any others you've seen in links from advertisers will work.
2. Find any generic link ID for the advertiser by logging into CJ and viewing the Links tab. A good link to use will be something that's not likely to be deleted, like their brand logo or product catalog.
3. Take note of your Publisher PID
4. URL-encode the actual destination you want to link to

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers work for me so I had to dig deeper myself.

If you are logged into CJ and go to `Links -> Link Tools` they have a `Deep Link Generator`. If you use that, you can see that all it does is append your current URL to `https://www.anrdoezrs.net/links/<property ID or publisher ID>/type/dlg/`.

I tried URLs with query parameters and it does not appear that their tool does any sort of encoding. In fact, if I urlencode my original URL, it ends up in an infinite redirect.

Usage example: `https://www.anrdoezrs.net/links/100298379/type/dlg/https://www.google.com/?q=cj`

Answer (score -1):

I recently found out that you can log into CJ and put a script onto your site which converts  links to affiliate links whenever possible: 
https://www.cj.com/publisher/deep-link-automation

This is not to say that it's perfect... advertisers can opt out of deep link automation. (as it says on there)